# Find which subvector in a nested vector contains a certain item

Tags: c++, search, vector

For a nested vector, I want to have a function that returns the index of the subvector that contains a certain item. For example, given this nested vector:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> vec {{1, 2, 3},
                         {4, 5, 6},
                         {7, 8, 9, 10}};
```

I want to have a function that acts like so:

```
find_subvector(vec, 5); //returns 1 because V[1] contains the element 5.
```

All of the items among all of the subvectors are unique.

I do have a solution currently, which is to iterate over all of the subvectors and use std::find():

```cpp
int find_subvector(const vector<vector<int>>& vec, int num) {
    for (int i {}; i < (int)vec.size(); i++)
        if (find(vec[i].begin(), vec[i].end(), num) != vec[i].end())
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

But I wanted to know if there was a faster solution, because I will be running this function repeatedly.

Comment: Have you tried solving this yourself? Please show your attempt.

Comment: Short answer: no there isn't. The only to find something in a vector is to search it. The End.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I've done that, as you can see in my edit, but I want a faster solution, as I'll be using this function a lot. If there is no faster way, I'll have to look for a faster implementation of the algorithm I'm trying to implement.

Comment: If the vector elements are sorted, you could easily binary-search for the values.

Comment: @humancompiler The vectors won't be sorted, but thanks for the suggestion.